# В чем причина ошибки "nothing to commit, working directory clean"?

Tags: git, intellij-idea, git-commit

Делал по инструкции настройку git, [документация](http://git-scm.com/book/ru/v1/Git-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5-%D0%9D%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80).

1. Создал папку  `git --bare init`
2. Перешел в папку проекта  `git init`
3. `git add .`
4. `git commit -m 'initial commit'`
5. `git remote add origin /var/www/git/rep`
6. `git push origin master`
7. У себя на компьютере `git clone ssh://eldos@10.0.20.24/var/www/git/rep`

И когда уже хочу сделать коммит в IntelliJidea, он находит изменные файлы, но не хочет коммитить.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так написано же серым по темно-серому: "nothing to commit, working directory clean"

Если видит, что ты что-то изменил то добавь это в измененные, а только потом комменть.

```
:~$ git status
:~$ git add .
:~$ git commit -m 'It is super puper commit! I\'ve fixed everything in the world!'
```