# Загрузка проекта на гитхаб с сохранением структуры каталогов

Tags: git, github

Я хочу залить на гитхаб свой веб-проект. Структура директорий выглядит так:

```
/home/box/web
          |---public
          |   |---img
          |   |---css
          |   |---js
          |---uploads
          |---etc
```

Репозиторий создан и путь к нему имеет вид %username%/nginx.git. Как мне правильно залить этот проект на гитхаб, чтобы при клонировании структура проекта и пути к директориям по возможности сохранялись?

Сейчас я сделал так: зашел в директорию web (cd web) и сделай в ней git clone пустого репозитория. Однако я получил не то, что хотел: сейчас к исходной структуре директорий добавилась еще директория nginx, которую я склонировал. То есть дерево каталогов такое:

```
/home/box/web
          |---public
          |   |---img
          |   |---css
          |   |---js
          |---uploads
          |---etc
          |---nginx
```

При попытке коммита получаю еррор:

> fatal: not a git repository (or any parent up to mount point /)

Что мне сделать, чтобы исходная структура директорий, то есть первая в этом посте, заливалась в мой репозиторий и при этом в проект не клонировалась папка nginx?

Comment: Раз вы зашли в папку веб, то нужно писать `git clone url .` (точку видите? текущая папка)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [git pull в существующий каталог](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/647839/git-pull-%d0%b2-%d1%81%d1%83%d1%89%d0%b5%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d1%83%d1%8e%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3)

Comment: @AK и получить от git отказ, т. к. папка не пуста, угу.

Comment: @D-side, прочитал ответы, одновил свой пост. Не получается ничего закоммитить, сообщение nothing to commit.

Comment: Откатил. Это уже другая, несвязанная проблема: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/409925/181100

Comment: Я выполнил git pull, git merge и обе команды выдали сообщение Already up to date. После выполнения git add --all команда git status показывает, что ничего не добавилось. В директории web лежат README.md  etc  public  uploads, но каталоги etc  public  uploads гит не хочет добавлять.

Comment: Дополнение: в команде git remote add origin /var/www/git/rep я указывал url своего репозитория на гитхабе.

Comment: Какая-то ерунда. Создал в public файл index.html с содержимым, и после этого удалось закоммитить public/index.html. Остальные пустые каталоги закоммитить не удалось.

Comment: Никакой ерунды. Пустые папки коммитить действительно нельзя за неимением в них содержимого: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/623608/181100

Answer (score 0):

Самый прямой вариант в таком случае получается:

1. `git init`, находясь в вашем каталоге `/home/box/web`.
2. Закоммитить что надо, настроить .gitignore для ненужного, всё это пока не обращая на github и прочее ремотное.
3. Через `git remote add` создать указание на репо на github, куда будете вливать.
4. Ещё раз всё проверить, что нет лишнего/потерянного - и через `git push` влить закоммиченное на github.